# Return a string values without using return statment in Java

Tags: java, return, hessian

Thank in advance.

I am looking for message type or anything which is fast and easy way to return a String value in Java.

for example. I have a method

```
void getStringvalues(int a, int b){

int c = a + b;

...
...
....


}
```

And the above Method is called from Hessian php server.

So i have to send a message back to php from Java like an acknowledgement. which has to be a string. Is there any way to do that.

I can use Return, but java method is dealign with huge db and caluculations. And php's session will expire until i finish the whole process and send return type "  ".
 at the end.

Or can i use return type in the beginning of the process ?

Thank again,

Comment: Do you like `return string;` ?

Comment: If you want to *return* a value, why would you not use a *return* type? Why are you trying to fight the language?

Comment: I can use Return, but java method is dealign with huge db and caluculations. And php will not wait until i finish the whole process and return ""
 at the end. @PeterLawrey

Or can i use return type in the beginning of the process ?

Comment: Why don't you do it in two steps: 1 - call the method responsible for the process and set a String with the value; 2 - wait a moment and call `getString` for the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your Java method to return an intermediate result, and then continue. So you have two solutions:

1. Split the method in two parts, and call each submethod from the client:

   ```
   intermediateResult = server.doFirstPart();
   server.doSecondPart();
   ```
2. Make the method do the second part in a separate thread:

   ```
   public String doEverything() {
       ...
       String intermediateResult = ...;
       Thread t = new Thread(...);
       t.start(); // launch the thread to compute the rest asynchronously
       return intermediateResult;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding you too well, but is that what you want?

```
public String getStringValues(int a, int b) {
    int c = a + b;
    String str = c + "";
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I can use Return, but java method is dealign with huge db and caluculations. And php's session will expire until i finish the whole process and send return type " ". at the end.

Or can i use return type in the beginning of the process ?